# Hide tags in wordpress posts (blogs) via CSS for logged-out users

Tags: css, tags, hide, loginstatus

I would like, as the title suggests, hide the tags under a wordpress post (aka blog) for logged-out users.
Usually this is not a problem by using CSS, just open the developer console (F12) and look up the class that you need to change.
The class name is "entry-tags" (I assume), or maybe it isn't - because when I used my usual CSS code for this, nothing happened:

```
body:not(.logged-in) .entry-tags{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Does somebody know a way around this? Maybe use something else beside CSS. IF you got a solution, please describe it in a little more detail (what to do, where to do it), because I'm by no means a coding savant).
If I hide it for logged-in users with this code, it works:

```
body.logged-in .entry-tags {
display: none !important;
}
```

Please help! Dumb, unnecessary comments also are a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I guess you realise that hiding stuff this way means that a user could see it if they used their browser devtools? Ie it’s not a way to hide stuff if hiding it is important.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, the target audience hardly knows what a browser is, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?:

```
body .entry-tags {display: none;}
body.logged-in .entry-tags {display: block;}
```

Whether the .entry-tags selector is correct or not, is for yourself to figure out and decide using the developer console/inspector.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much! So I assume it had to be changed in the "body" as well. I have a long way to go at this point, because I can hardly figure out what your code did. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: The 2 style rules I gave only target the .entry-tags.

The selector rule 'body .entry-tags' will find all '.entry-tags' that exists within the body.

The selector rule 'body.logged-in .entry-tags; will find all 'entry-tags' within the body that has the class 'logged-in'.

This is CSS 'specificity' - the more 'specific' rule takes precedence. You can read more about CSS specificity here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: Ps. to be honest, I'm a little unsure why your first rule didn't work... :D body:not(.logged-in) .entry-tags. But I can highly recommend W3Schools for learning CSS.